# Mount a remote GPU locally on Rocky Linux

Tags: unix, remote, gpu

I am doing some work on a server which has 1TB RAM, 100CPUs, and 1000TB storage. My work involves very large datasets.

One specific I am trying to run would benefit immensely from a GPU, it is ML inference. However, my server does not have a GPU.

At home, I have a desktop running Ubuntu with a powerful-enough NVIDIA GPU.

Is there a way I can somehow mount the GPU on my desktop to the server?

I understand there would be a lot of network transfer, however it is still worth it. I did a test when I mounted the server filesystem using SSHFS and ran the process locally and it was significantly accelerated even with my 12 core CPU.

However the process I am now looking to run requires both high RAM, and a GPU, so it must be run on the server.

Comment: I dont think that a datacenter throughput would fit at your home. why don't you remote desk into that equipment? at the current stage, this question is off topic

Comment: The only solution I can see is juice, https://github.com/Juice-Labs/Juice-Labs/wiki/

Comment: Post this as answer to get karma.